# script needs to give an answer and save it after every 100,000 seconds (variable from dataset)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to coding and am working on a little script for school. It is for the project HiSparc, to measure cosmic radiation, and thus uses a custom made module called sapphire, hence why some of the pieces script I'll show may be new. I'm working to create a graph that shows how over the years, the amount of events these dectectors detect changes, if at all.

These HiSparc detectors create their own tables which can be downloaded and dealt with by Sapphire. Here I use the quick_download function which just downloads yesterdays data for station 501. If you run this script it gives a total events of around 54000.

```
import sapphire
from sapphire import quick_download
data = quick_download(501)

events_table = data.root.s501.events
events = sum(1 for line in events_table)
print(events)
```

I would like to get this number every 100000 seconds or so, the HiSparc data includes timestamps for every event in GPS time, so it should be possible, I do not have a clue how to split this graph, and then make a new file with these events.

a 100000 seconds is around a day, and if I use this quick_download function (24hours) and searh the timestamp for event 0 which is of course event 1 and event 50000, which is around a full day later i get a difference in timestamp of:

```
events_table[0]['timestamp']
Out[7]: 1575936003

events_table[50000]['timestamp']
Out[8]: 1576016547
```

+- 80000, so if I run the "events =" line every 100000 seconds one would expect results of around 60000 events. The idea of this script is to find out if this number of events changes over years.

```
start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

esd.download_data(data, '/s501/events/timestamp', 501, start, end)
```

which a script like this, which downloads the data from all the years it was online, could determine. 
If you need any more information please ask, and thanks very, very much for helping out!

Greetings,
Seth

Comment: I may have a misunderstanding, but how will you be able to come to a conclusion about the behavior over the years by only using a few *days* of sequential data? Shouldn't you be taking representative samples of HiSparc data from the past X years instead of the next Y days? It looks like you have 20 years of data at the end, so why do you need the next few days of data?

Comment: yeah all you need is to look at your historical data (which apparently you have in the esd object?) and plot daily or weekly or whatever totals as func. of time from 2000 to 2020 . quick_download isn't actually necessary if you have the historical data.  Also the 'gps time' is also known as epoch time, number of secs. since jan1 1970.